# resizable div area

Tags: javascript, html

I have two divs that I am using within a fieldset to keep separate some of my page areas

```
    <fieldset style="padding: 20px, 20px, 20px, 20px; background-color: #EAEAEA;">
    <div class="col1" >
    ...
    </div>
    <div class="col2">
    ...
   </div>
```

with the following style:

```
.col1 {
    clear:both;
    float:left;
    overflow:hidden;
    width:10%;
}
.col2 {
    float:left;
    width:90%;
}
```

First, I wanted to have a little way of visually separating them, so I added to col1:

```
    border-right:2pt solid black;
```

Well, this added the black line, but now my col1 div is ABOVE my col2 div. How can I correct this? I thoguht maybe it was a margin thing, but adding 2pts of right margin didnt help.

Also, I'd eventually like to make this divider a place where I can pan left/right to resize the two div relative to each other (i.e. make one 30% wide, the other 70%, or 10%, 90% etc)

Comment: I think the col2 div should have been below the col1 div all along. Div tags are normally rendered using display:block, wich means that they will go to a new line. This can be changed by changing the display to display:inline or by using position:absolute or similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your using % as your width you are using 100% of the screen resolution so you need to reduce the width of col2.  Since your adding a 2pt border which essentially takes you over the 100% you need to make sure you adjust the width.  You could either adjust col2 or col1, I adjusted col2 below for you.

```
.col1 {
    clear:both;
    float:left;
    overflow:hidden;
    width:10%;
    border-right:2pt solid black;
}
.col2 {
    float:left;
    width:89%;
}
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/rhoenig/UUjM4/)

Answer (score 0):

You can't add a border to a screen that is already 100% filled.

Eg. if your screen is 1000px, and you have it split in 10%/90% you now have two objects that are 100px and 900px respectively.  Adding the border would make it 102px and 900px which gives a total of 1002px (2px bigger than your screen) and therefore it'll wrap.

Either use fixed sizes for the width or put another container inside it.